# Set of bounded diameter is contained in a spherical ball

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, spherical-geometry

In the following I consider spherical distances.

Say a subset $X$ of the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ is convex if it contains all geodesic segments between its points. Let $k<\frac{2\pi}{3}$, and suppose that $X$ has diameter $<k$. What is the optimal function $f(k)$ such that $X$ has to be contained in a disk of radius $f(k)$?

(For $k\geq\frac{2\pi}{3}$ we have $f(k)=\pi$, considering an equilateral triangle)

Sharp upper bounds for $f$ could also be useful. In case this is heavily dependent on the dimension $n$, I am happy with $n=3$.